# How does the electro-optic bandwidth of an optical modulator limit its data rate?

Tags: optics, photonics

For example, given a PIN diode silicon photonic modulator with a 3dB electro-optic bandwidth of 5Ghz - what is the limit to the data rate? Is it related to the Nyquist frequency?

Also, for that modulator, if you were sending a digital signal - would there be a limit to the baud rate (or the total data rate?) set by the electro-optic bandwidth?

Comment: Google the Shannon-Hartley theorem.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, the answer is that the electro-optic (EO) bandwidth will limit the data rate since it describes how quickly an applied electric field can "switch" the modulator on or off.

Let's keep in mind what the EO bandwidth represents. Generally, our modulator takes some electrical signal and outputs some optical signal. How does this happen? In the case of the PIN modulator, this electrical signal is applied to both ends of the junction. When the holes and electrons in the junction "see" this applied field, we know that they begin to move to a new equilibrium position based on said field. The new carrier concentrations in the junction in turn changes the refractive index that the optical signal "sees," changing how it propagates and interacts with other signals. **Though how this specifically translates to a modulated signal depends on the modulator, this is what converts the electrical signal into an optical one - the changing electric signal changes the carrier concentration, which changes the refractive index of the waveguide, which changes the optical signal.**

But this brings up the question: *how long does this sequence of events - electrical signal --> carrier concentration --> index --> optical signal - take to complete?* This is effectively what the EO bandwidth is describing - how quickly can a change in the applied electric signal translate to a change in the optical signal? A difference in this conversion efficiency between two different modulation speeds means that the conversion process is not being fully completed for the higher modulation speed. **The 3-dB bandwidth specifically is answering the question "At what frequency/speed is this modulator only half as effective at changing the index?"** You can then imagine at some point, you begin to change the bias so quickly that none of the electrons can generate/recombine quickly enough to change the index.

The last point to remember is that we would like for our modulator to introduce as little distortion to our original electric signal as possible. **What this means from a frequency perspective is that our modulator must convert all of the frequencies within our input signal just as effectively as one another.** It then becomes clear that once our modulator's conversion efficiency starts changing, we can no longer say that our input signal experiences no distortion. This is why the EO bandwidth determines our data rate - whatever signal we want to transmit needs to be within the EO bandwidth to not suffer distortion. This point should automatically address the second part of your question as well.

I most likely oversimplified some points, but overall picture should help. You should read about carrier lifetimes and recombination for a more rigorous explanation of the physics. This [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_generation_and_recombination) isn't a bad place to start, and most solid-state physics books will cover this as well. Hope this helps!